# Get the HTTP request body being sent

Tags: http, go, client, httprequest, http-get

I am doing a request to a https based API.
When entering the request URL in Chrome, everything works fine. When doing the same request using the `net/http` package in Go, I get an error about missing subdomain:

```
"error": {
  "type": "ApiUnknown",
  "message": "No api specified (via subdomain)"
}
```

I assume Chrome and Go somehow sends slightly different http requests, so, I need to know what those differences might be.

In Chrome I can use the Developer tools to see the sent request.

*How can I get the HTTP request body being sent from the `http` package?*

I can do the following:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    urlStr := "https://api-name.subdomain.domain.org/page?param=value"

    //client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", urlStr, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    req.Write(os.Stdout) // Will this output be equal to the one being sent to the server?
    //resp, err := client.Do(req)
}
```

**Output:**

> GET /page?param=value HTTP/1.1
>   Host: api-name.subdomain.domain.org
>   User-Agent: Go 1.1 package http

**Playground:** http://play.golang.org/p/Oku0O1yiBt

But I am not sure whether the Transport adds something before the request is sent, or if this is actually all there is.

Comment: Additional headers may be set when the request is sent (e.g. `Authorization` if there is basic auth credentials in the URL, `Referer` in case of redirects, etc).  You haven't really provided much information about why your server might be rejecting your request though.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge: Yes, I assumed that might be the case. And no, I haven't provided much info because I really don't know. That is why I would like to see the actual request body. I take the exact same `urlStr` and paste it into Chrome on the same computer and get a different response. I've added the actual response that the Go http request gives me.

Comment: I might add that, while the urlStr isn't the actual url (well, duh), it has the same structure. It even has a dash in the `api-name`, so for a moment I thought Go might have URL encoded the dash, but that is not the case.

Comment: Well, one option would be to write a small web server (or even jut use netcat) and try sending requests from both Go and Chrome.

Comment: Maybe http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequestOut may help.

Comment: @Intermernet: That seems to do what I wish to accomplish. An answer to my question (but something else must be acting up, since even if I copied every single header, it still gives me a different response. But that remains my headache). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at the net/http std lib sources. As James Henstridge already answered: a few additional authorization and transport related headers might be added. But this is all strictly adhering to the protocol. So I wouldn't assume that there is anything wrong there.

Your code at the bottom of your example should really print all relevant information. Now it depends on your specific use case why your request fails.

Did you specify the correct subdomain (as stated by the error message)?

Do you have a `Content-Type` header set? The server might check for an appropriate `Content-Type` depending on your chosen subdomain.

These are just a few assumptions I can make at this stage.